# how to add Admob Ads in a class that extends ListActivity

Tags: java, android, admob

i want to add java code of Admob Ads in OnCreateMethod. But my java class extends ListActivity. 
Please tell me how to add admob ads in this class.

If i add the code in the class that extends ListActivity it crashes the App.

Please provide me a solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

**my MainActivity java code**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
    List headlines;
    List links;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        new MyAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object,Void,ArrayAdapter>
    {
        @Override
        protected ArrayAdapter doInBackground(Object[] params)
        {
            headlines = new ArrayList();
            links = new ArrayList();
            try
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://feelthesport.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss");
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                // We will get the XML from an input stream
                xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");
                boolean insideItem = false;

                // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                    {
                        if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                        {
                            insideItem = true;
                        }
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
                        {
                            if (insideItem)
                                headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                        }
                        else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
                        {
                            if (insideItem)
                                links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                        }
                    }
                    else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                    {
                        insideItem=false;
                    }
                    eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
                }

            }
            catch (MalformedURLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (XmlPullParserException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayAdapter adapter)
        {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse((links.get(position)).toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public InputStream getInputStream(URL url)
    {
        try
        {
            return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show where your code crashes and what error message you get.

Comment: it crashes when i open my app. i pasted code in my oncreatemethod

Comment: Do you have a stack trace from your debugger at the point where you app crashes? Did you test your code line by line to see where the problem is?

Comment: just leave crashing point, if i delete admob code it does not crash, it is crashing because i am pasting admob code in listactivity. please tell me how to add admob in listactivity.

Answer (score 0):

I think so rather adding to ListActivity.
Add AppCompatActivity & make use of RecyclerView
Add Adapter for AdMob Create custom layout whatever you want this could be helpful even if you you want to add your item along with AdMob.
Once added CustomerAdapterClass, call **setAdapter()**

Done your view will get poopulated. 
Thanks.

Comment: but appcompatactivity will not show Listview in app?

Comment: I will show you up example for RecyclerView with AdMob @AmanArya